# How to update timzone settings in Jre?

Tags: java, eclipse, timezone, rcp

I am currently working on a project where in three location the timezones are coming incorrectly.I tried updating my tzmappings file from jre 1.8 .In this process I could able to see the correct time in one location and other location time are still wrong.We embedded the jre with our application and for that we were using jre 1.6.I understand upgrading to new jre i.e jre 1.6->Jre1.8 will be solve this problem.But let me know if anything apart from this i can do to resolve this.

Update: Tried running TZupdater but ends up getting NPE detail stack trace below

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TzRuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.main(TimezoneUpdater.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.run(TimezoneUpdater.java:215)
        at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.main(TimezoneUpdater.java:643)
```

Comment: [Timezone Updater Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html)

Comment: i tried using tzupdater.jar but it throws NPE

Comment: Too bad. You may want to search the web for that error and/or post the stacktrace (either in this question or a new one, which you find more appropriate).

Comment: Updated the stacktrace here

Comment: From JRE, it won't work. update from $JAVA_HOME/bin/java